# Как вставить QScrollArea в Qwidget?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwidget, qtabwidget, qscrollarea

Есть небольшой код для магазина, в котором с помощью **QTabWidget** будет несколько вкладок,  в которых будут фотографии товаров, и я хочу сделать так, чтобы в каждой вкладке было множество товаров, и чтобы они туда помещались нужно использовать **QScrollArea**, однако не понимаю как правильно это сделать, посмотрел информацию в интернете, однако это не помогло.

Вот сам код:

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MARKETPLACE")
        #Создаем выравнивание для страницы
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1920,1042))

        #Создаем label для фото
        self.photos = QLabel()
        self.photos.setFixedSize(QSize(1920, 440))
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("view.jpg")
        self.photos.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        vbox.addWidget(self.photos)

        #Создаем QTabWidget для товаров 
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12)
        self.tab.setFont(font)
        self.tab.setStyleSheet(TabStyle)

        #Создаем вкладку с товарами по скидке
        self.tab.addTab(sales(), "SALES")
        #One more tab
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss"),"ss")
        #One more tab
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss"),"ss")
        #ONE MORE TAB
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss"),"ss")

        vbox.layout().addWidget(self.tab)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
    

class sales(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
    
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self)

        self.gbox = QGridLayout()
        self.gbox.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.gbox.setSpacing(10)
        #первый виджет
        self.widget1 = QLabel()
        self.widget1.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("ЛЕС.png"))
    
        self.childwidget1 = QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.childwidget1.setGeometry(0,275,450,25)
        self.childwidget1.setStyleSheet("background-color:  white; color: black")
        self.childwidget1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget1.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget1)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(430,0,20,25)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")

        #второй
        self.widget2 = QWidget()
        self.widget2.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        #третий
        self.widget3 = QWidget()
        self.widget3.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget3.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        #четвертый
        self.widget4 = QWidget()
        self.widget4.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget4.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        #пятый
        self.widget5 = QWidget()
        self.widget5.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget5.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")
        #шестой
        self.widget6 = QWidget()
        self.widget6.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget6.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink")
        #седьмой
        self.widget7 = QWidget()
        self.widget7.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget7.setStyleSheet("background-color: purpule")
        #восьмой
        self.widget8 = QWidget()
        self.widget8.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget8.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")



        #Добавляем виджеты в layout
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget1, 0, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget2, 0, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget3, 0, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget4, 0, 3)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget5, 1, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget7, 1, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget8, 1, 3)
        
        
        
        self.setLayout(self.gbox)


#Design for QTabWidget
TabStyle = """
 
QTabBar::tab {
    border: 2px solid #C4C4C3;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB;
    border-top-left-radius: 16px;
    border-top-right-radius: 16px;
    min-width: 32ex;
    padding: 2px;
    background: Beige;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
 
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спросите если что-то не понятно.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Sales(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):        
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout(self)                                  # +++
        layoutV.addWidget(self.scroll)                               # +++
        
        self.widget = QWidget()                                      # +++  !!!
        
# -        self.scroll.setWidget(self)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.widget)                           # +++  !!!

        self.gbox = QGridLayout(self.widget)                         # +++ self.widget
        self.gbox.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10)
        self.gbox.setSpacing(10)
        #первый виджет
        self.widget1 = QLabel()
        self.widget1.setFixedSize(450, 300)
        self.widget1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(       # +++ scaled
            450, 300))
        self.childwidget1 = QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.childwidget1.setGeometry(0, 275, 450, 25)
        self.childwidget1.setStyleSheet("background-color:  white; color: black")
        self.childwidget1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12))
        self.childwidget1.setText("2000")
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self.childwidget1)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(430, 0, 20, 25)
        self.btn1.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")

        #второй
        self.widget2 = QWidget()
        self.widget2.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget2.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        #третий
        self.widget3 = QWidget()
        self.widget3.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget3.setStyleSheet("background-color: green")
        #четвертый
        self.widget4 = QWidget()
        self.widget4.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget4.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        #пятый
        self.widget5 = QWidget()
        self.widget5.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget5.setStyleSheet("background-color: grey")
        #шестой
        self.widget6 = QWidget()
        self.widget6.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget6.setStyleSheet("background-color: pink")
        #седьмой
        self.widget7 = QWidget()
        self.widget7.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget7.setStyleSheet("background-color: purpule")
        #восьмой
        self.widget8 = QWidget()
        self.widget8.setFixedSize(450,300)
        self.widget8.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")

        #Добавляем виджеты в layout
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget1, 0, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget2, 0, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget3, 0, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget4, 0, 3)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget5, 1, 0)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget6, 1, 1)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget7, 1, 2)
        self.gbox.addWidget(self.widget8, 1, 3)
        
# -        self.setLayout(self.gbox)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MARKETPLACE")

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

#        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1920,1042))

        #Создаем label для фото
        self.photos = QLabel()
#        self.photos = QWidget(self)
        self.photos.setObjectName("photos")                          # +++
        '''
#        self.photos.setFixedSize(QSize(1920, 440))
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("boy.jpg").scaled(
            self.width(), self.height()//2)
        self.photos.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        '''
        vbox.addWidget(self.photos, 1)                               # +++ 1

        #Создаем QTabWidget для товаров 
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        font = QtGui.QFont("Century Gothic", 12)
        self.tab.setFont(font)
# -        self.tab.setStyleSheet(TabStyle)

        # Создаем вкладку с товарами по скидке
        self.sales = Sales(self)                                     # +++
# -        self.tab.addTab(Sales(), "SALES")
        self.tab.addTab(self.sales, "SALES")                         # +++
        
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss1"),"ss1")
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss2"),"ss2")
        self.tab.addTab(QLabel("sss3"),"ss3")

# -        vbox.layout().addWidget(self.tab)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tab, 1)                                  # +++ 1
# -        self.setLayout(vbox)


# - TabStyle = """
qss = """                                                  /* <---- */
#photos {                                                  /* <---- */
    border-image: url(boy.jpg) 0 0 0 0  ;                  /* <---- */
}                                                          /* <---- */  
QTabBar::tab {
    border: 2px solid #C4C4C3;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB;
    border-top-left-radius: 16px;
    border-top-right-radius: 16px;
    min-width: 32ex;
    padding: 2px;
    background: Beige;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;
}
 
QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
 
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                                  # +++ <----
        
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(1200, 600)                                     # +
    
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**boy.jpg**

[image: boy.jpg]

Comment: Для чего в классе **Sales** прописываем **parent = None**?

Comment: @ivapop в вашем случае это добавление ни на что не влияет, можете убрать. Но тогда и при создании экземпляра класса `self.sales = Sales()` уберите `self`.